# I am getting this error after created a dynamic feature in android studio 4.0

Tags: android, android-studio-4.0

[image]**Invoke-customs are only supported starting with Android O (--min-api 26)**

I am getting this error after created a dynamic feature in android studio 4.0

Answer (score 0):

after spending hours on this I finally got an answer by changing the minimum 26

```
defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 26
    targetSdkVersion 29
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"

    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
```